# Rails validation for has_one relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, mongoid, associations

I have two model like:

```
class Employee
  field :name
  field :login, type: Boolean
  has_one :user
end

class User
  field :username
  field :email
  belongs_to :employee
  validates_presence_of :username
end
```

I want to create an user account when create employee if check box of login field is checked. For this my new action of employees controller is:

```
def index
    @employee = Employee.new
    @employee.build_user
end
```

For this my form code is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee) %>
<%= f.input :login, :as => :boolean, :label => "Create User" %>
<div class="create-user" style="display: none">
  <%= f.simple_fields_for :user do |u| %>
    <%= render 'user_fields', {f: u} %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
    <button class="btn btn-info">Save Change</button>
 <% end %>
```

and the _user_fields.html.erb is:

```
<%= f.input :username %>
```

I want to validate the user model when check_box of :login field is checked. On unchecked condition the form should be submit. What is the better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got its solution:

```
class Employee
  field :name
  field :login, type: Boolean
  has_one :user
  has_one :user, :class_name => "User", :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user, :reject_if => :login_blank
  def login_blank
    return false if self.login == true
    return true if self.login == false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can move your user validation into employer model ?

something like code below should solve your problems

```
validates_presence_of :username, :if => login?
```

What do you think?

Comment: This code works if :login and :username fields are of same module, but these fields are in model with association.

Comment: if you for sure want to separate that I think that you should use polymorphic model user. And employer should be an user with additional validation. Otherwise it will be hard. You can take a look on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

Answer (score 0):

maybe use validates_associated:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#validates_associated

or delegation + validates presence might also work

> delegate :username, to: :user, allow_nil: true
>
> validates :username, presence: true, if: :login